# Create a chart with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-rest-api, chart

I would like to create a chart with chart JS. I would like to load a JSON from my AGE rest and after that, create a cumulative chart with the length of my polylines.

My code blocks when I try to load data,it gives me a error 'undefined (reading Map)'. I don't know what to do.
I work with 2 fields: the name of the bus lines (libelle) and the date of creation (miseservice).

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//var url = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 var url ="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/1/query?where=1%3D1&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&relationParam=&outFields=miseservice%2Clibelle&returnGeometry=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&havingClause=&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&multipatchOption=xyFootprint&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnTrueCurves=false&returnCentroid=false&timeReferenceUnknownClient=false&sqlFormat=none&resultType=&datumTransformation=&lodType=geohash&lod=&lodSR=&f=pjson"
 xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
 xmlhttp.send();

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    //console.log(data.count)
    service = data.miseservice.map(function(elem){
        return elem.miseservice;
    })
    libelle = data.libelle.map(function(elem){
        return elem.libelle;
    })
    //console.log(population)

    const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: service,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Libelle',
                data: libelle,
                backgroundColor: "#ff335e"
                
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}
The data looks like this
[image]

```
{
  "features": [
{
  "attributes": {
    "miseservice": 1633392000000,
    "libelle": "Lianes 1"
  }
},
{
  "attributes": {
    "miseservice": 1568592000000,
    "libelle": "Lianes 1"
  }
},
{
  "attributes": {
    "miseservice": 1636329600000,
    "libelle": "Lianes 10"
  }
},
{
  "attributes": {
    "miseservice": 1636329600000,
    "libelle": "Lianes 10"
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Code or JSON posted as an image is often illegible, and would require anyone who could help to retype your code/data to provide a solution. Text in Questions should always be posted as text in the Question body.

Comment: Thank you @Vince  ,I've just changed my post :)

Comment: Should you be using `service = data.map(function(elem){` instead of `service = data.miseservice.map(function(elem){`?

Comment: Are you using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript? If so, you don't have to load the data manually.